# Manually/Artificially throwing a DOMException with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to manually throw a DOMException error in pure JavaScript? [Documentation I've read](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch09s10.html) suggests it should be relatively easy to construct (at least in Java.)

However, in Chrome, following code returns `TypeError: Illegal constructor`:

```
// DOM SYNTAX_ERR (12)
var myDOMException = new DOMException(12,"I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.");
```

Regrettably, this is what I expected after reading [the W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-17189187), which don't appear to specify a constructor at all. (As an aside, while I'm not particularly 'au fait' with IDL, I would have assumed their variant would support specification of constructors.)

Frustratingly, the DOMException class lurks tantalisingly in the global scope. How can I use it? *Can* I use it?

**Update**

Since I wrote this, I've made a couple of discoveries - namely:

```
var myDOMException = DOMException.constructor(12,"Error Message");
var myDOMException2 = DOMException.constructor.call(DOMException,DOMException.SYNTAX_ERR,"Error Message");
```

Looks like it worked!

...not so fast.

```
$> myDOMException instanceof DOMException
false
$> myDOMException2 instanceof DOMException
false
```

And possibly even more offputting:

```
$> myDOMException.constructor
function Number() {
    [native code]
}
```

As always, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Update #2**

Just to clarify my reasons for returning a DOMException object as opposed to a more generic Error - I'm trying to implement the [WHATWG's Timed Text Track spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#timed-text-tracks) in pure JavaScript. There are a number of instances where a proper solution would be required to return a DOMException object, specifically one with a code of 12 (SYNTAX_ERR.)

Comment: Java and JavaScript are like car and carpet (to quote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/58693#58693)).  So that documentation is irrelevant.

Comment: I was more interested in it as a DOM implementation, not as a 'similar to JavaScript' language, which I'm well aware it's not (name aside.)

Comment: If you would elaborate on **why** you want to be able to throw such a thing, you might get some interesting suggestions.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks - see my revised question above.

Comment: Internal objects do lots of weird things and break tons of rules. The reason calling DOMException.constructor works is because the _proto_ for a DOMException isn't a function as normal constructors are, it's an object, even though the object signature is a function (don't ask me why). Also, normally, the constructor property will always be functions, because anything you instantiate is a function. The place you want to find the proper constructor for an object is within prototype.constructor, which will almost always point back at the object that contains the prototype, unless you override it.

Comment: related: https://readable-email.org/list/public-webapps/topic/dom4-constructor-for-domexception

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Firefox, at least, `DOMException` is not a function. It is [an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMException) that defines several constants.

```
 typeof DOMException === 'object' // true (not 'function')
```

It could be used like this:

```
try {
    throw DOMException;
} catch(e) {
    if (e === DOMException)
        console.log("caught DOMException")
}
```

This works if you're trying to signal a `DOMException` but don't need an actual instance of `DOMException`.

### Ugly, ugly hack (that basically works)

If you absolutely need an instance of `DOMException` that has the `SYNTAX_ERR` code, you could perform an action that causes one to be created and `throw` that:

```
function createSyntaxException() {
    try {
        // will cause a DOMException
        document.querySelectorAll("div:foo");
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
}

throw createSyntaxException();
```

The details of the thrown exception won't match your specific situation, of course, but the resulting object will have the correct code and pass `instanceof` checks.

```
var e = createSyntaxException();
console.log(e instanceof DOMException); // true
console.log(e.code === e.SYNTAX_ERR); // true
```

You could mitigate the details issue by subclassing `DOMException` and adding getters/setters for each of its (read-only) properties.

```
function DOMExceptionCustom() {
    var message;
    this.__defineGetter__("message", function(){
        return message;
    });
    this.__defineSetter__("message", function(val){
        message = val;
    });
}

// subclass DOMException
DOMExceptionCustom.prototype = createSyntaxException();

var err = new DOMExceptionCustom();
err.message = "my custom message";
```

The resulting object has the desired properties:

```
console.log(err.code === err.SYNTAX_ERR); // true
console.log(err.message); // "my custom message"
console.log(err instanceof DOMExceptionCustom); // true
console.log(err instanceof DOMException); // true
```

Comment: So the best way to do it would be something along the lines of `throw DOMException.SYNTAX_ERR;`? I don't gain anything from returning a special kind of object?

Comment: @Christopher - That would be perfectly fine. I've added some other examples to my answer.

Comment: @Christopher, but `DOMException.SYNTAX_ERR` is a number, not a DOMException.  It's meant as a value of `DOMException.code`.  This is relevant because some catch blocks do filter using `instanceof`, so they'll ignore any number you throw.

Comment: @matthew-flaschen That's why I wanted to return the object itself in the first place. (See my revised question.)

Comment: @Christoper - Right, now that I see you actually need an instance of `DOMException` I've added a very hacky way to accomplish it. I don't know that you'll be able to create a custom instance, though.

Comment: @lwburk Just before you posted that update to your answer, I noticed that this seemed to work in Chrome:

    `var someError = new Object();
    someError.code = 12;
    someError.message = "SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12: You must specify a track kind";
    someError.name = "SYNTAX_ERR";
    someError.__proto__ = DOMException.prototype;`

It also avoids the requirement for getters/setters, as the properties are mutable before the DOMException prototype is applied (and at least in Chrome, mutable afterward as well.) Thanks for your help on this one! (P.S. Sorry about the line breaks!)

Comment: @Christopher - Be careful with `__proto__`. It's non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @lwburk Seems like your method is the one to use - my method breaks totally in Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: The "ugly, ugly hack" is just what I needed in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my crack at it. Solution based on ECMAScript 5 and WebIDL. 
I've [discussed this](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-script-coord/2012JanMar/0458.html) with the W3C/ECMAScript join task force that are working on WebIDL. They said it's basically impossible to do because it relies on internal platform behaviour... but here is something that may be close enough.

```
function CustomDOMException(code, message) {
    //throw on missing code
    if (typeof code !== "number") {
        throw TypeError("Wrong argument");
    }

    //we need the codes, to get the "name" property.  
    var consts = {
        1: "INDEX_SIZE_ERR",
        3: "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR",
        4: "WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR",
        5: "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR",
        7: "NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR",
        8: "NOT_FOUND_ERR",
        9: "NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR",
        11: "INVALID_STATE_ERR",
        12: "SYNTAX_ERR",
        13: "INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR",
        14: "NAMESPACE_ERR",
        15: "INVALID_ACCESS_ERR",
        17: "TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR",
        18: "SECURITY_ERR",
        19: "NETWORK_ERR",
        20: "ABORT_ERR",
        21: "URL_MISMATCH_ERR",
        22: "QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR",
        23: "TIMEOUT_ERR",
        24: "INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR",
        25: "DATA_CLONE_ERR"
    }
    if ((code in consts) === false) {
        throw TypeError("Unknown exception code: " + code);
    }

    //props for adding properties
    var props = {};
    //generate an exception object 
    var newException;
    try {
        //force an exception to be generated; 
        document.removeChild({})
    } catch (e) {
        //use it as the prototype  
        newException = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(e));
    }
    //get the name of the exception type        
    var name = consts[code];

    //add the properties
    var props = {value: null, writable: true, enumerable: false, Configurable: true};
    //name
    props.value = name; 
    Object.defineProperty(newException, "name",    props);
    props.value = code; 
    Object.defineProperty(newException, "code",    props);
    props.value = message; 
    Object.defineProperty(newException, "message", props);

    //Make sure it "stringifies" properly 
    var finalMessage;
    var obj = this;
    if (typeof message === "function") {
        finalMessage = function() {
            return message.call(newException)
        }
    } else {
        finalMessage = function() {
            return name + ": DOM Exception " + code;
        }
    }
    props.value = function() {
        return finalMessage.call(newException)
    }

    Object.defineProperty(newException, "toString", props);
    return newException;

}
```

And some tests:

```
// Throws SYNTAX_ERR    
console.log(new CustomDOMException(12)); 

// Custom message 
console.log(new CustomDOMException(1, "ERROR!")); 

// Custom message 
console.log(new CustomDOMException(1, function() {
    return "Custom Err:" + this.name + " : " + Date.now()
}));

// Throws TypeError     
try {
    new CustomDOMException(2)
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);    
}

// Throws TypeError
try {
    new CustomDOMException()
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);    
}    

// Throws TypeError    
try {
    new CustomDOMException("Wee!")
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);    
}

//Check the inheritance chain     
var ext = new CustomDOMException(17);
var isInstance = ext instanceof DOMException;
console.log("instanceof DOMException: " + isInstance)​
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an old question,

I have found out the correct way to do it. So I share it here.

- `error.code` is meaningful but cannot be used for error construction.
- `error.code` will automatically match the `error.name` e.g. `TimeoutError`, `AbortError`, `TypeError`, etc.

As you want to error to have the `error.code = DOMException.SYNTAX_ERR (12)`, you can use `document.querySelector('a::b')` to create that error and find out its error name.

[image: img]

Then you can have

```js
throw new DOMException("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.", "SyntaxError")
```

[image: img]

You can also change `DOMException` to `MyOwnError`.

```js
    class MyOwnError extends DOMException{
        constructor(msg){
            super(msg, 'SyntaxError');
        }
    }
```

```js
throw new MyOwnError("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.", "SyntaxError")
```

[image: img]

[image: img]

```js
class MyOwnError extends DOMException {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg, 'SyntaxError');
  }
}

const err = new MyOwnError("Oops...")
console.log(err.code === err.SYNTAX_ERR); // true
console.log(err.message); // "my custom message"
console.log(err instanceof MyOwnError); // true
console.log(err instanceof DOMException); // true
throw err
```